# Docker-compose persistent volume issue with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, docker-volume, persistent-volumes

I have a problem with mounting a volume for Elasticsearch in docker-compose. The mount is for another disk, mounted at: `/mt/sda/` I am using the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.0"
services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elastic-container-rescue
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.15.0
    volumes:
      - es-data:/mt/sda/es-data
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
      - "network.host:0.0.0.0"
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=$ES_PASS
      
    ports:
      - 9300:9200
    networks:
      - elastic
networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  es-data:
    driver: local
```

When I check it with `docker volume inspect`, it still shows incorrect **mountpoint** - it should be: `/mt/sda/es-data`

```
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2021-11-09T13:51:05+01:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.project": "rescue-es",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.25.5",
            "com.docker.compose.volume": "es-data"
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/rescue-es_es-data/_data",
        "Name": "rescue-es_es-data",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
```

Any suggestions on how to assign the correct mountpoint?

Comment: It is showing the expected path. container path you have configured it the wrong way.

Comment: So how should I configure the path?

Answer (score 5):

#### Elasticsearch Docker Container with Persistent Volume Configuration

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.0"
services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elastic-container-rescue
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.15.0
    volumes:
      - es-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
      - "network.host:0.0.0.0"
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=$ES_PASS
      
    ports:
      - 9300:9200
    networks:
      - elastic
networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  es-data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: /mt/sda/es-data
```

Comment: If the answer was useful, does it worth getting the reputation? You missed only container and host volume configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately... you need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.